# match '+' in a string with str.match javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I was looking at this example:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_match_regexp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to perform a global search for the letters "ain+" in a string, and display the matches.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
    var res = str.match(/ain+/g);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And it's what I need, but if I add a '+' at the end of 'ain' it does not work, how should I do it?

Comment: What do you need, when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: *how should I do it?* The way you should do it is to read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers), or any good regexp tutorial, or play with your regexp in a sandbox like regex101.com.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`+` is a repetition character which means `1 or more`. If you want to literally search for `+` then you need to escape it like this:

```
str.match(/ain\+/g)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to perfom a global search for the letters "ain+" in a string, and display the matches.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "The rain+ in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
    var res = str.match(/ain\+/g);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, thanks for this, I was trying to do the same in the example page but I think it just does not work there, greetings!

Comment: @Rugleh please note that I've changed `var str` in `myFunction()`. I have changed `rain` to `rain+` maybe that's the reason it's working here.

Answer (score -1):

/ain+/ matches ain, ainn, ainnn, ainnnn... "ai" and one or more "n".

Answer (score -1):

### Why

Since `+` is a repetition symbol for regular expressions, `/ain+/` matches for `ai` followed by one or more `n` (including the `n`s), such as `ainnn`, `ain`, `ainn`.

### How

If you want to make it match for *character `+`*, **you have to escape** the `+`, i.e. use `/ain\+/g` instead.

Comment: Im trying to match a string that contains "ain+" on it, including the + symbol

Comment: @Rugleh Updated :)

Comment: thanks a lot, I was trying to do that in the example page but I think it just dont work there

Answer (score -2):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain ain+";
  var res = str.match(/ain\+/g);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "In the sentence: [" + str + " ] " + res + " was found.";
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to perfom a global search for the letters "ain+" in a string, and display the matches.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```